# Import.io - Get Dataset Through RESTful API - Get Fresh Data

Tags: import.io

Is there a way to refresh a dataset through the RESTful API?

The following API method gets the dataset, but I am not sure if it gets fresh
data when called as it uses a 'snapshot':

/store/connector/{id}/_attachment/snapshot/{snapshot}

http://api.docs.import.io/#%21/Connector_Methods/getDataSnapshot

The whole purpose is to use Chain API to generate a Dataset and get it over REST with fresh data when called.